# Getchar gets char only one time

Tags: c

Even if `while` is true `getchar` iterates one time. I tried my code with `getchar` in `while` condition and body, but it doesn't work.

```
int main() {
    char* s = malloc(sizeof(char)) /*= get_string("Write number: ")*/;
    char a[MAXN];
    int i = 0;
    do {
        a[i] = getchar();
        *s++ = a[i];
        i++;
    } while (isdigit(a[i-1]) && a[i-1] != EOF && a[i-1] != '\n' && i< MAXN);
    /*while (isdigit(*s++=getchar()))
        i++;*/
    *s = '\0';
    s -= i;
    long n = conversion(s);
    printf("\n%lu\n", n);
}
```

Comment: _Exactly_ what keys did you press as input?  Don't forget that <Enter> is a key.

Comment: `char* s = malloc(sizeof(char))` is only good for the `""` string as `s` has only 1 byte of memory.  Try `malloc(MAXN + 1)`

Comment: I removed the extra things not related to the do/while loop you say doesn't work, and it works for me. https://ideone.com/RGNfK1

Comment: what are you trying to accomplish with `*s++ = a[i];` because s++ immediately takes you out of bounds of allocated memory after one iteration as @chux notes above. Maybe you mean to declare `char *s = &a[0];` after declaring `a`?

Comment: @RetiredNinja Nice code aside from pedantic UB when `a[i-1] < 0` in `isdigit(a[i-1])`

Comment: Note the `(isdigit(a[i-1]) && a[i-1] != EOF && a[i-1] != '\n' && i< MAXN)` prevents inclusion of a _sign_ as part of conversion.  Note: the `&& a[i-1] != EOF && a[i-1] != '\n'` is not needed as `'\n'` and `EOF` are never _digits_.

Comment: @chux `i` is never less than 1, it is incremented inside the do/while that will always execute at least once. Not how I would write it, but I did not want to change the example more than necessary to show to original loop given in the question does work. The problem is elsewhere. I don't see the purpose of the `s` pointer at all in the given code since `a` will also decay to a pointer if passed to the conversion function.

Comment: @RetiredNinja Agree will all the good insights you said, except my [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54048054/getchar-gets-char-only-one-time?noredirect=1#comment94931572_54048054) was about `a[i-1] < 0`, not `i < 0`.  Alternatives include `isdigit((unsigned char) a[i-1])` and `a[i-1] >= '0' && a[i-1] <= '9'`.

Comment: @chux Ah, I misread. Same problem with `EOF`, but as you noted it isn't necessary to check it in addition to the digit check that would fail. :)

Comment: when asking a question about a run-time problem, as this question is doing, post a [mcve] including the inputs.  Then we do not have to guess about the parts of the code that are not posted.

Comment: OT: when calling any of the heap allocation functions: `malloc` `calloc` `realloc`, always check (!=NULL) the returned value to assure the operation was successfull,  If not successful, then call `perror( "malloc failed" );` followed by: `exit( EXIT_FAILURE );

Comment: regarding: `char a[MAXN];`  the macro `MAXN` is not defined in the posted code.

Comment: regarding: `*s++ = a[i];`  Since the character pointer 's', only is pointing to a single allocated character allocation.  So after the first character is input, then 's' is incremented, then the next pass through the loop will be past the allocated memory area.  This results in undefined behavior

Comment: regarding: `char* s = malloc(sizeof(char))`  Rather than only allocating a single character, strongly suggest: `char* s = malloc( MAXN +1)` so enough heap memory is allocated for the actual max input length plus one more byte for the (later in the code) appending of the NUL byte

Comment: regarding: `s -= i;`  rather than this 'iffy' operation, suggest in the while loop that 's' never be changed, rather use: `s[i] = a[i]`

Comment: regarding: `long n = conversion(s);`  where is the definition for the function: `conversion()`?  Suggest calling `strtol()` instead

Comment: regarding: `printf("\n%lu\n", n);`  this is trying to output a `long unsigned int` value, BUT the variable 'n' is declared as a 'long int', not a 'long unsigned int'  Suggest: `printf("\n%ld\n", n);`

Comment: @user3629249 Thanks, you are nice to me and gave helpful advices.

Comment: @chux, if <Enter> is a key, what do I press to input some character?

Comment: @NikitaKokorin "what do I press to input some character?" --> depends on how you answer the [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54048054/getchar-gets-char-only-one-time?noredirect=1#comment94931489_54048054).

Comment: @chux I press <Enter>. I press digit followed by <Enter>.

Comment: NikitaKokorin, <digit> < Enter> attempts to go through the `do {} while` loop twice as at the end of the 2nd iteration, the loop stops because `isdigit('\n')` is false.  Code attempts to form in `s` and `a`, with the 3: `digit`, `'\n'`, `'\0'`.  Yet `s` has only room for 1 `char`.  What is being entered is not the problem,.  How input is being used is a problem.  Instead drop the `s` an only save 2: `digit`, `'\0'`.  Both answers below provide more details.

Comment: @chux When I print <digit> < Enter> my virtual machine assumes it's 2 characters. And when it iterates 2nd time it doesn't ask for character but takes character number 10.

Answer (score 1):

As others have pointed out, there isn't much use for `s` because `a` can be passed to `conversion`. And, again, the `malloc` for `s` only allocates a single byte.

You're incrementing `i` *before* doing the loop tests, so you have to use `i-1` there. Also, the loop ends with `i` being one too large.

Even for your original code, doing `int chr = getchar(); a[i] = chr;` and replacing `a[i-1]` with `chr` can simplify things a bit.

Better yet, by restructuring to use a `for` instead of a `do/while` loop, we can add some more commenting for each escape condition rather than a larger single condition expression.

```
#define MAXN        1000

int
main(void)
{
    char a[MAXN + 1];
    int i;

    for (i = 0;  i < MAXN;  ++i) {
        // get the next character
        int chr = getchar();

        // stop on EOF
        if (chr == EOF)
            break;

        // stop on newline
        if (chr == '\n')
            break;

        // stop on non-digit
        if (! isdigit(chr))
            break;

        // add digit to the output array
        a[i] = chr;
    }

    // add EOS terminator to string
    a[i] = 0;

    unsigned long n = conversion(a);
    printf("\n%lu\n",n);

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Code does not allocate enough memory with `malloc(sizeof(char))` as that is only 1 byte.

When code tries to save a 2nd `char` into `s`, bad things can happen: *undefined behavior* (UB).

In any case, the allocation is not needed.

---

Instead form a reasonable fixed sized buffer and store characters/digits there.

```
// The max digits in a `long` is about log10(LONG_MAX) + a few
// The number of [bits in an `long`]/3 is about log10(INT_MAX)
#define LONG_DEC_SZ (CHAR_BIT*sizeof(long)/3 + 3)

int main(void)  {
  char a[LONG_DEC_SZ * 2]; // lets go for 2x to allow some leading zeros

  int i = 0;
  int ch; // `getchar()` typically returns 257 different values, use `int`

  // As long as there is room and code is reading digits ...
  while (i < sizeof a && isdigit((ch = getchar())) ) {
    a[i++] = ch;
  }
  a[i++] = '\0';
  long n = conversion(a);
  printf("\n%ld\n", n);
}
```

---

To Do: This code does not allow a leading sign character like `'-'` or `'+'`